# Weighted average of curves

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

Suppose I have a resource the value of which depends, e.g., on a normal probability density function. That is,

$$Value_\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}}$$

Now, on the other hand, the value of $\mu$ is given by a random variable governed by *another* probability distribution, say the standard normal distribution $N(0, 1)$.

How can I calculate the expected curve $Value(x)$? I should point out that I am interested in the general case, for any arbitrary curves.

Comment: $E(X)=E(E(X\mid \mu))=E(\mu)=0$

Comment: Right, but I'm not looking for the expected value of $Value(x)$, but the expected *curve* that, given an arbitrary $x$, will give its value.

Comment: I guess the example I'lve given in my question is bad in that it's very symmetric. I should perhaps point out that I am interested in the general case, for arbitrary curves.

Comment: $f_X(x)=\int f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)f_Y(y)\,dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model for a typical observation $X$ conditional on unknown parameter $\theta$ is $f(x|\theta)$. As a function of $\theta$, $f(x|\theta)$ is called *likelihood*.
The functional form of $f$ is fully specified up to a parameter $\theta$. The parameter $\theta$ is supported by the parameter space $\Theta$ and considered a random variable. The random variable $\theta$ has a distribution $\pi(\theta)$ that is called the *prior*. The distribution $h(x,\theta) =f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)$ is called the joint distribution for $X$ and $\theta$. The joint distribution can also be factorized as
$$
h(x,\theta) =\pi(\theta|x)f(x)
$$ and the distribution $\pi(\theta|x)$ is called the posterior distribution for $\theta$, given $X=x$. The marginal distribution $m(x)$ can be obtained by integrating out $\theta$ from the joint distribution $h(x,\theta)$
$$
m(x)=\int_{\Theta}h(x,\theta)\mathrm d\theta=\int_{\Theta}f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)\mathrm d\theta
$$
Therefore, the posterior $\pi(\theta|x)=\frac{h(x,\theta)}{m(x)}$ can be expressed as
$$
\pi(\theta|x)=\frac{f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)}{\int_{\Theta}f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)\mathrm d\theta}
$$

Assume that an observation, $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and known variance $\sigma^2$. The parameter of interest, $\mu$ also has normal distribution with parameters $\nu$ and $\tau^2$.

So yo have the Bayesian model $X|\mu\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\mu\sim\mathcal N(\nu,\tau^2)$.
The joint distribution has density
$$\begin{align}
h(x,\mu)=f(x|\mu)\pi(\mu)&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\tau^2}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{(\mu-\nu)^2}{2\tau^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\tau^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\rho}\left[\mu-\rho\left(\frac{x}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\nu}{\tau^2}\right)\right]^2-\frac{(x-\nu)^2}{2(\sigma^2+\tau^2)}\right)\\
&=\pi(\mu|x)m(x)
\end{align}
$$
where $\rho=\frac{\sigma^2\tau^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2}$. Observing that $\rho\left[\frac{x}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\nu}{\tau^2}\right]=\frac{\tau^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2}x+\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2}\nu$, we have that
$$
\mu|X\sim \mathcal N\left(\frac{\tau^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2}X+\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2}\nu,\frac{\sigma^2\tau^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2}\right)
$$
and 
$$
X\sim \mathcal N\left(\nu,\sigma^2+\tau^2\right)
$$
You may *check* that by the elementary properties of conditional expectation,
$$
\Bbb E(X)=\Bbb E\left(\Bbb E(X|\mu)\right)=\Bbb E(\mu)=\nu
$$
amd 
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)=\Bbb E\left(\mathrm{Var}(X|\mu)\right)+\mathrm{Var}\left(\Bbb E(X|\mu)\right)=\Bbb E(\sigma^2)+\mathrm{Var}(\mu)=\sigma^2+\tau^2
$$

> For you particular problem $X|\mu\sim\mathcal N(\mu,1)$ and $\mu\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, that is you have to put $\sigma=\tau=1$ and $\nu=0$, and you'll find that $X\sim\mathcal N(0,2)$.